# Including headers and CSS in different directories

Tags: php, html, include

This must be a simple fix, but I just can't figure it out!

I am including the header via PHP into each new page, the header contains the CSS and scripts etc.

Only problem is since the page is in a different directory, when I link to the header like ../header etc it looks fine but the included scripts, are the included via a short URL e.g.  /js/script.js

Which means on the page (in another directory) the scripts do not work!

I'm finding it hard to explain but take a look at this:

```
http://www.healthygit.com/
```

If you view the source all the scripts link fine.

Now look at this:

```
http://www.healthygit.com/fitness/running.php
```

If you try to click on a script to view it, it takes you to a 404 or in this case 302's you to the homepage.

Comment: Use absolute URLs from the root rather than relative URLs from each file.

Comment: You probably need to use absolute urls as opposed to relative urls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy peasy, your source for the scripts, stylesheets etc. should have a `/` in front of them, that way the header file will always refer to the files from the root of the site.

I.e. this:

```
src="js/whatever.js"
```

Should become

```
src="/js/whatever.js"
```

This way it will always look for the files from the root of the site.
The same applies with CSS files, i.e. `/css/whatever.css`.